# Laravel 5 - Loading Public JS / CSS / HTML Files From Custom Folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel serves client side (HTML, CSS, JS) files from the `/public` folder by default.  I am currently transitioning a Blade based front-end to an Angular based one.  As a result, I am mixing Blade templating with Angular templating.  I am using Blade layouts to generate a navbar, footer, and other common views while I transition the body content of my pages to Angular.

I have a folder constructed just for storing Angular files.  My current app structure looks something like this:

```
-MyApplication
    -angular
    -app
    -bin
    -bootstrap
    -config
    -database
    ....
```

Is there anyway for Laravel to load my assets - stored in the `/angular` folder?  I want to keep all my Angular files in one place, in standard Angular structure, as opposed to spreading them out and placing them in the `/public` Laravel folder.

Comment: have you seen [laravel angular](https://github.com/jadjoubran/laravel5-angular-material-starter)? it may be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a symbolic link inside the `public` directory to your intended `angular` directory. Open your terminal and create a symbolic link like so:

```
ln -sfv ~/path/to/MyApplication/angular ~/path/to/MyApplication/public/angular
```

Don't forget to update the `~/path/to/MyApplication` to your actual Laravel directory. Now you may refer to the javascript file inside the `angular` directory like this on your blade template:

```
<script src="{{ asset('angular/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Hope this help!